# What Part of Speech Modifies a Preposition?

Tags: parts-of-speech, prepositional-phrases

Is there a rule for which part of speech modifies a preposition? What part of speech is the italicized *halfway* in the following sentence?

"He stopped *halfway* out the door."

Comment: Directly into, partially around, perfectly on, ostensibly for, all use adverbs. Looks like halfway is working as an adverb here.

Comment: "Out the door" is not a preposition, but a prepositional **phrase**. And it's a predicate phrase, so it must be modified by adverbs.

Comment: PPs can also be modified by NPs as in "We left a few minutes before the end"; "I live a mile beyond the Rose & Crown pub. And also by prepositions, as in "I'm sure it's down in the basement"; "I think Dad may be round at the pub".

Comment: [A team at Sussex University](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=essay---parts-of-speech&site=1) proposed that these _Prepositional Phrase Modifiers_ were distinct enough to merit a non-traditional label.

Comment: Very interesting quote from the Sussex team:
"There exists a set of words which modify prepositional phrases. Among them are straight, just, way and right, as in straight into the hole, just behind the house, way over the limit and right beside the bed. These words have received little attention from grammarians. Perhaps they deserve to constitute an additional part of speech."

Comment: @John There can be no justification for creating a distinct part of speech solely for those words that function as modifiers in PP structure. That's a ludicrous idea by Sussex. The words "straight", "right", "way" etc., occur as adjectives, but they are adverbs when they modify prepositions.

Comment: Sounds like a debate over transubstantiation. Does the adjective **really** become an adverb, or is it merely a symbol of adverbiness? And who is the Justiciar before whom answers to such questions must be justified?

Comment: "Adverb that follows the prepositional phrases becomes the modifier of prepositional phrases, while adverb that precedes the prepositional phrases becomes the modifier of the preposition only." quoted from http://linguasphereus.blogspot.com/2011/04/structure-of-modification.html Original attributed source: Structure of American English by W. Nelson Francise. Page 297-325